# Rails 4 and ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

My app uses Rails 4, and I'm using the ckeditor gem and turbolinks.

In my form partial I call the ckeditor as so:

```
.form-group
  = f.label :content, "Содержание", class: "col-sm-3 control-label"
  .col-sm-8
    = f.text_area :content, class: "form-control ckeditor", rows: 50
```

When I go to this page, I don't see ckeditor. Only after I update page does it appear. But why? What am I doing wrong? I think it's because of turbolinks. How do I solve this?

Comment: In my apps when I use the Ckeditor gem, I usually put     f.cktext_area :content, :ckeditor => {:language => "fr"} instead of text area.

Comment: @codingaddicted how woth this code could i disable some panels in editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this gem: [ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor)

Gemfile for the last version

```
gem "ckeditor", :git => "https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor.git"
```

Application.js

```
//= require ckeditor/init
```

In the views as the readme said:

```
<%= form_for @page do |form| -%>
  ...
<%= form.cktext_area :notes, :class => 'someclass', :ckeditor => {:language => 'uk'} %>
...
<%= form.cktext_area :content, :value => 'Default value', :id => 'sometext' %>
...
<%= cktext_area :page, :info, :cols => 40, :ckeditor => {:uiColor => '#AADC6E', :toolbar => 'mini'} %>
...
<% end -%>
```

Use cktext_area instead of text_area

for the rails 4 assets you need

```
//= require ckeditor/override
//= require ckeditor/init
```

And there's a trick for the compilation of assets, you need to look into the readme.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You need to override the js config: app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js. You need to check the doc of the gem (see the link in my answer) and the official ckeditor doc for the possible changes in the panel.

Comment: but this is gem... how to override if it didn't exist in assets?

Comment: You just have to create it with the good path and your file version will be used instead of the one from the gem. In the read me of the gem you can see "In order to configure the ckeditor default options, create files: .... ". The author is talking about the js and the css files. Here is an exemple of a configuration file I made for an app of mine: http://pastebin.com/fFk6cEJF But to call this particular configuration instead of the standard you need to do it like this:    <%= f.cktext_area :notes, :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'mini'} %>. Hope it helps!